# SoftKeyboard not closing on activity onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Edit:*Problem has been solved thanks to @dharms*

I am trying to control the keyboard open and close function in an activity.
The activity has 2 edit texts (first one for a title, second one for another function)

[This is the activity screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPfEG.jpg)

I would want the keyboard it to open and focus on the first edit text when the activity is open, hide when I click anywhere outside of the keyboard and hide when the activity is closed. I have been able to complete all of these tasks except the last one: the keyboard loses focus and remains open when the activity is closed.

NOTE: The keyboard doesn't close only when Ii close the activity right after opening it. If I close the keyboard and click the editTExt again, it works perfectly... Help?

I provided the Activity java file and xml file and the app's manifest. I believe that no other part of the app interferes with the problem and I have already checked that.

Activity:

```
    public class AddSettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //todo Variables
    private int seekbarProgress;
    int maxNumber;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean hasItemList;
    // for editing an item
    boolean isEditing;
    int itemPosition;

    //todo Views
    private ConstraintLayout addSettingConstraint;
    private TextView maxNumberText;
    private EditText editTextTitle;
    private SeekBar seekBarMaxNumber;
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar addSettingsToolbar;
    private Button addItemListButton;
    private TextView maxNumberTextRepositioned;
    private ImageButton addItemButton;
    private EditText itemEditText;
    private ImageButton deleteItemsList;
    private TextView itemsNumberTitleTextView;
    private ImageView addItemEditTextBackground;
    private ImageView itemListBackground;

    //todo Components
    private ItemListAdapter itemListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView itemListRecyclerView;
    private ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper;
    private View itemListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_setting);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();

        //todo Views Initialized
        addSettingConstraint = findViewById(R.id.add_setting_constraint_layout);
        editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
        seekBarMaxNumber = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        seekBarMaxNumber.setMax(34 /*is 36 - 2, to correctly set minimum value to 2*/);
        maxNumberText = findViewById(R.id.max_number_text);
        addItemListButton = findViewById(R.id.add_items_btn);
        // With Item List
        maxNumberTextRepositioned = findViewById(R.id.max_number_text_with_items);
        addItemButton = findViewById(R.id.add_item);
        itemEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_item_string);
        deleteItemsList = findViewById(R.id.delete_item_list);

        itemsNumberTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.items_max_num_title_text_view);
        addItemEditTextBackground = findViewById(R.id.item_edit_text_background);
        itemListBackground = findViewById(R.id.item_list_background);

        hasItemList = false; //default Value for adding a setting. If true, It means the setting has Items (strings entered by users, attached to the number)
        isEditing = false; //Default. This is used to edit an item in the list
        maxNumber = 2; // Lowest number should be 2
        seekBarMaxNumber.setProgress(0);
        maxNumberText.setText(String.valueOf(2));
        addSettingConstraint.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));

        //todo Toolbar
        addSettingsToolbar = findViewById(R.id.add_setting_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(addSettingsToolbar);

        //todo  Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        // Enable the Up button
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);

        //todo RecyclerView
        itemListRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.item_list_recycler_view);
        itemListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        itemListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //todo Adapter
        itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter();
        itemListRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(itemListAdapter);
        mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(itemListRecyclerView);


        //todo SET LAYOUT IF IS EDIT SETTING
        if (intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID)) {
            setTitle(R.string.edit_setting_toolbar_title);
            editTextTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TITLE));
            editTextTitle.setSelection(editTextTitle.getText().length()); //this moves the cursor to the end of the String

            seekbarProgress = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MAX_NUMBER, 2);
            seekBarMaxNumber.setProgress(seekbarProgress);
            maxNumberText.setText(String.valueOf(seekbarProgress));
            maxNumber = seekbarProgress;

            hasItemList = intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_HAS_ITEMS, false);
            if (hasItemList) {
                //hide views
                seekBarMaxNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                maxNumberText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                addItemListButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                // Show Views for Item List
                itemListRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                maxNumberTextRepositioned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addItemButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deleteItemsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                itemsNumberTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemListBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addItemEditTextBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //variables
                items = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ITEMS_LIST);
                itemListAdapter.setItems(items);
                maxNumberTextRepositioned.setText(String.format("%s", itemListAdapter.getItems().size()));
            }

        } else {
            setTitle(R.string.add_setting_toolbar_title);
        }





        // Show Keyboard
        showKeyboard(editTextTitle);


        addItemEditTextBackground.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        addItemButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        itemEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

        set.clone(addSettingConstraint);
        // The following breaks the connection.
        set.clear(R.id.item_list_recycler_view, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        // This is the new connection
        set.connect(itemListRecyclerView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        // Save changes
        set.applyTo(addSettingConstraint);


        seekBarMaxNumber.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                maxNumberText.setText(String.valueOf(progress + 2));
                maxNumber = progress + 2;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });


        //todo Add and Delete Items Button
        // ADD ITEM LIST
        addItemListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hasItemList = true;
                changeStateHasItems(hasItemList);
            }
        });

        //DELETE ITEM LIST
        deleteItemsList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (itemListAdapter.getItems().size() > 0) {
                    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSettingActivity.this, R.style.DeleteItemListAlertDialog)
                            .setTitle("Delete Item List?")
                            .setMessage("If you delete the item list of this Setting, you won't be able to recover it.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes, delete it!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    hideKeyboard();

                                    hasItemList = false;
                                    changeStateHasItems(hasItemList);
                                    itemListAdapter.setItems(items); // This clears the items in the ItemListAdapter (item list is in fact null)

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Abort", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                } else {
                    //This part of code is copied from the method above!
                    hideKeyboard();

                    hasItemList = false;
                    changeStateHasItems(hasItemList);
                    itemListAdapter.setItems(items); // This clears the items in the ItemListAdapter (item list is in fact null)
                }
            }
        });

        //todo HAS ITEMS Methods:
        // Add an Item on ENTER button press
        itemEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    saveItem(isEditing);
                    // Return true to tell system the right key has been pressed
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        editTextTitle.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    editTextTitle.clearFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Add an Item on ADD button press
        addItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveItem(isEditing);
            }
        });

        // Edit Item when Clicking it
        itemListAdapter.setOnItemClickLister(new ItemListAdapter.OnListItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View itemView) {
                String title = itemListAdapter.getItems().get(position);
                itemEditText.setText(title);
                itemListView = itemView;
                itemPosition = position;
                addItemButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_green);
                isEditing = true;
                itemEditText.setSelection(itemEditText.getText().length()); //This moves the cursor to the end of the string

                //Show Soft Keyboard
                showKeyboard(itemEditText);
            }
        });

        itemEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    if (isEditing) {
                        String itemString = itemEditText.getText().toString();
                        if (itemString.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(AddSettingActivity.this, getString(R.string.add_setting_toast_no_title), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (itemString.length() > 23) {
                            Toast.makeText(AddSettingActivity.this, getString(R.string.add_setting_toast_item_title_is_too_long), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Save Item String
                            items.set(itemPosition, itemString);
                            itemListAdapter.setItems(items);

                            // Reset View and Variables
                            itemEditText.setText("");
                            //itemListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item);
                            addItemButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_dark);
                            itemPosition = 0;
                            itemListView = null;
                            isEditing = false;
                        }

                    }
                    hideKeyboard(itemEditText);
                }
            }
        });

        editTextTitle.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    addItemEditTextBackground.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    addItemButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    itemEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

                    set.clone(addSettingConstraint);
                    // The following breaks the connection.
                    set.clear(R.id.item_list_recycler_view, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
                    // This is the new connection
                    set.connect(itemListRecyclerView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
                    // Save changes
                    set.applyTo(addSettingConstraint);


                } else {

                    hideKeyboard(editTextTitle);

                    addItemEditTextBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    addItemButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    itemEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

                    set.clone(addSettingConstraint);
                    // The following breaks the connection.
                    set.clear(R.id.item_list_recycler_view, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
                    // This is the new connection
                    set.connect(itemListRecyclerView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.edit_text_item_string, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
                    // Save changes
                    set.applyTo(addSettingConstraint);


                }
            }
        });


        LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        lbm.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("sendItemListData"));

    }

    public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null) {
                items = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ITEMS_LIST);
                maxNumber = items.size();
                itemListAdapter.setItems(items);
                maxNumberTextRepositioned.setText(String.valueOf(maxNumber));
            }
        }
    };


    //todo CHANGE STATE
    private void changeStateHasItems(boolean hasItemList) {
        if (hasItemList) {
            // Hide Views
            maxNumber = 0;
            maxNumberTextRepositioned.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            seekBarMaxNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            maxNumberText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            addItemListButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // Show Views for Item List
            itemListRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            maxNumberTextRepositioned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addItemButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            itemEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            deleteItemsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            itemsNumberTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            itemListBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addItemEditTextBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            //Show Items List Views
            itemListRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            seekBarMaxNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            maxNumberText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            addItemListButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Hide No Item List Views
            maxNumberTextRepositioned.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            addItemButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            itemEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            deleteItemsList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            itemsNumberTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            itemListBackground.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            addItemEditTextBackground.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Transition Max Num from Number of Items to SeekBar
            maxNumber = itemListAdapter.getItems().size();
            items.clear();
            itemListAdapter.setItems(items);
            if (maxNumber > 1) {
                maxNumberText.setText(String.valueOf(maxNumber));
                seekBarMaxNumber.setProgress(maxNumber - 2);
            } else {
                maxNumberText.setText("2");
                seekBarMaxNumber.setProgress(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveItem(boolean isEditing) {
        if (!isEditing) {
            String itemString = itemEditText.getText().toString();
            if (itemString.trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(AddSettingActivity.this, getString(R.string.add_setting_toast_no_title), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (itemString.length() > 30) {
                Toast.makeText(AddSettingActivity.this, getString(R.string.add_setting_toast_item_title_is_too_long), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                items.add(itemEditText.getText().toString());
                itemListAdapter.setItems(items);
                maxNumberTextRepositioned.setText(String.format("%s", itemListAdapter.getItems().size()));
                itemEditText.setText(""); // resets edit text input every time an item is added

                //todo Change RecyclerView Position when adding and removing item !
            }
        } else {
            String itemString = itemEditText.getText().toString();
            if (itemString.trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(AddSettingActivity.this, getString(R.string.add_setting_toast_no_title), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (itemString.length() > 30) {
                Toast.makeText(AddSettingActivity.this, getString(R.string.add_setting_toast_item_title_is_too_long), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Save Item String
                items.set(itemPosition, itemString);
                itemListAdapter.setItems(items);

                // Reset View and Variables
                itemEditText.setText("");
                //itemListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item);
                addItemButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_dark);
                itemPosition = 0;
                itemListView = null;
                this.isEditing = false;

                // Hide Soft Keyboard
                hideKeyboard();
            }

        }
    }

    private void saveSetting(boolean hasItemList) {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();

        //todo Check Title isn't empty
        if (title.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (title.length() > 15) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Title has to be shorter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TITLE, title);


        //todo Insert Extras
        if (hasItemList) {

            if (itemListAdapter.getItems().size() < 2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Setting should have at least 2 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            items = itemListAdapter.getItems();
            maxNumber = itemListAdapter.getItems().size();
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MAX_NUMBER, maxNumber);
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ITEMS_LIST, items);
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_HAS_ITEMS, true);
        } else {
            Log.d("AddActivity", "Has Item List is false, max number is = " + maxNumber);
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MAX_NUMBER, maxNumber);
        }
        int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID, -1);

        if (id != -1) {
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID, id);
        }

        // Pass Position (From Main Edit Interface to onResult in Main)
        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, -1);
        data.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, position);

        // send results
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();

    }

    public void showKeyboard(View view) {
        view.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }

    public void hideKeyboard() {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(View view /*edit text*/) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        hideKeyboard();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_setting_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save_setting:
                saveSetting(hasItemList);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

XML File of the Activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/add_setting_constraint_layout"
    tools:context=".AddSettingActivity"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/setting_title_edit_text"
        android:hint="@string/add_setting_edit_text_setting_title"

        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/greyText"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally, the part of the manifest related to the activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".AddSettingActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:parentActivityName="io.github.davidwickerhf.diceroller.MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="io.github.davidwickerhf.diceroller.MainActivity"
        />
    </activity>
```

As I said before, Everything works except for the keyboard not closing when closing activity.

I know it's a lot of code to go through, so I thank you before even if you don't get to a solution.

Comment: Try using onPause() instead.

Comment: @dharms YOU ARE A SAINT! Thank you for responding! It works in o Pause()! I really appreciate your response!

Comment: @Dan Harms Hi, can you explain why you recommended onPause() rather than onDestroy()?  Why would onPause() work in this case and not onDestroy()?

Comment: @AJW onPause() will be invoked whenever the activity loses focus, not just when it is destroyed. Examples would be using the home button rather than back button, another activity coming out of the background or otherwise gaining focus, etc.

Comment: @Dan Harms Ah yes, understood.  Thanks for the reply, cheers!